# Can I just send "Hello World" to the port of another IP?

Tags: server, ip, protocols, ping

I'm just discovering how networking works.

Is it possible to just send "Hello World" to a specific port of an IP?

Just `"Hello World"` nothing else.

It is fine if it becomes `"null is ",0` on the other end....

But is it possible, assuming that I have control over the other device.

The message should travel over the 'internet we all use'.

If it isn't possible, what is the minimal needed information to connect to any other IP over the internet.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use:

```
echo <message> | netcat <host> <port>
```

This works with tcp and udp protocols

Comment: I am sorry if I was unclear in the question's description, but I don't want any header (or minimal header) in the string to be echoed.